# Dovecot Sieve Trace does not create a log

Tags: dovecot

i have a problem with my Dovecot 2.2.33.2 and Sieve Pigeonhole 0.4.21.

I want to trace, which sieve rules are used if a mail get moved or deletet or rejected oder what ever sieve does with the mail.

So i have found the sieve-trace settings but sieve dont create a trace logfile.

I have setup the trace debug in my `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/90-sieve.conf` and thats look like this:

```
    ## TRACE DEBUGGING
  # Trace debugging provides detailed insight in the operations performed by
  # the Sieve script. These settings apply to both the LDA Sieve plugin and the
  # IMAPSIEVE plugin.
  #
  # WARNING: On a busy server, this functionality can quickly fill up the trace
  # directory with a lot of trace files. Enable this only temporarily and as
  # selective as possible.

  # The directory where trace files are written. Trace debugging is disabled if
  # this setting is not configured or if the directory does not exist. If the
  # path is relative or it starts with "~/" it is interpreted relative to the
  # current user's home directory.
  sieve_trace_dir = ~/sieve/

  # The verbosity level of the trace messages. Trace debugging is disabled if
  # this setting is not configured. Possible values are:
  #
  #   "actions"        - Only print executed action commands, like keep,
  #                      fileinto, reject and redirect.
  #   "commands"       - Print any executed command, excluding test commands.
  #   "tests"          - Print all executed commands and performed tests.
  #   "matching"       - Print all executed commands, performed tests and the
  #                      values matched in those tests.
  sieve_trace_level = "actions"

  # Enables highly verbose debugging messages that are usually only useful for
  # developers.
  sieve_trace_debug = yes

  # Enables showing byte code addresses in the trace output, rather than only
  # the source line numbers.
  #sieve_trace_addresses = no
```

At the `sieve_trace_level` i have tried everything, i have used every parameter with and without semicolon´s but i dont get a log in my users sieve directory.

My user directory of my virtual user is here `/var/mail/vhosts/<domain>/<user>/` so the log schould be createt under `/var/mail/vhosts/<domain>/<user>/sieve` but it dosn´t ..

My mail log does not log eny sieve errors, do you have a idea, what i can do? I only want see all steps, which my mail proceed.

best regards

Comment: Same here with Debian 11, dovecot 2.3.20-3

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that `dovecot -n` showed a different directory than I had configured in `90-sieve.conf`, because I overrode it in `local.conf`.

That directory did not exist, thus dovecot did not log anything.